# primeng datatable error when typing

Tags: angular, primeng

Good morning, I have a system in Angular language that uses the PrimeNG component. My problem is with DataTable, when I am typing something in the filter box it sometimes "eats" some letter that I type. What can it be ?

Follows an example:

https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/135965/19224060/211e009e-8ec9-11e6-94c6-a0ba70b2459c.gif